# POSTing data to a servlet 3.0 with jQuery 2.0.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, servlets, post

I am trying to make a web app which is supposed to call a **servlet** from a **jsp** page thanks to the **jQuery**'s function `$.post(...)` and publish the results on the same page. 
So far I had no luck, even after searching the web. 
Being a noob, I am probably doing something wrong but I cannot realise what.

I managed to streamline the problem into the following *MWE*.
The servlet in my `Test` project looks like this:

```
@WebServlet("/servlet")
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            doPost(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            String temp = request.getParameter("param");
            request.setAttribute("result", temp);
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp");
            view.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

If my `index.jsp` is the following, the web app works as expected:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Result: ${result}</p>
    <form method="post" action="/Test/servlet">
        <input name="param" value="value" />
        <button type="submit">Send!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I deploy my web app to my **Tomcat 7.0.47** container, in fact, I get a page with `Result:`, an input field initialised to `value` and a `Send!` button. 
If I press the button, the servlet is properly reached in `/Test/servlet` and the page then reads `Result: value`. In my project, however, I am supposed to use **jQuery**'s function `$.post(...)` to post parameters to the servlet and get attributes back, so I replaced my `index.jsp` with the following code:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        var value = $('#field').val();
        alert('Sending: ' + value);
        $.post('/Test/servlet', {
            param : value
        }, function(result) {
            alert('Done!');
        }, 'html');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Result: ${result}</p>
    <form action="/">
        <input id="field" value="value" />
        <button type="button" onclick="send()">Send!</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This time, If I deploy the web app and I press the button, I get two message windows.
The first tells `Sending: value` (meaning that **jQuery 2.0.3** is properly resolved) and the second `Done!`. 
Clearly, the page is not updated to reflect `Result: value`. 
Since the servlet has not been changed, I suspect that the servlet is not properly resolved.
So I tried to replace `/Test/servlet` with: `/Test/servlet/`, `Test/servlet/`, `Test/servlet`, `/servlet/`, `/servlet`, `servlet/` and `servlet`, with no luck. 
I noticed however that I do not get the `Done!` message (such as she I use `/servlet` or similar).

So, to conclude, what I am doing wrong? 
Can you explain me what is going on in the background to help me understand? 
Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks to the help of the [coding_idiot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566092/coding-idiot), I finally managed to understand why my code was not working.
I am going to share my findings below in the hope that they can also help someone else.

Simply put, the two methods described above are **not** equivalent, or at least not in these terms.
The first method, in fact, calls the servlet which produces a page that replace the initial page.
The second method, instead, invokes the servlet which generates a page that is returned back to the initial page which is not necessarily replaced.
The returned data must be injected somewhere to let the user see it, as suggested by the [coding_idiot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/566092/coding-idiot).

This is how I refactored the above code to get a working example.
The code of the servlet is left unchanged but the second to last line of the `doPost(...)` method which now reads:

```
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher("/results.jsp");
```

Then, I divided the above page into two distinct parts.
The first one is `index.jsp` that is automatically loaded by the container when a user request the web app address:

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*"
    contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        $.post('/Test/servlet', {
            param : $('#field').val()
        }, function(result) {
            $("#result").html(result);
        }, 'html');
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input id="field" value="value" />
        <button type="button" onclick="send()">Send!</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result">
        <p>Result: --</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice that the form is more or less the same as before, but now there is a `<div id="result">` which contains the default value for the `result`.
The other difference is in the function `send()` where the `/Test/servlet` is invoked to compute a `result`; this `result` is then injected into the above `<div id="result">` after the *Send!* button is pressed.
As I showed above, the servlet forwards the request into a response for `results.jsp` which is simply:

```
<p>Result: ${result}</p>
```

Now when the user presses the `Send!` button, the value of the input field is passed to the servlet as a parameter, the servlet converts the parameter into an argument and forwards it to given page.
When this page is interpreted the expected message (`Result: value`) is composed and returned to `index.jsp` where it is included into the `<div id="result">` and finally becomes visible.

I wonder whether it is possible to make `$.post(...)` exactly works as in the first method without declaring the `<div id="result">` immediately inside the `<body>`. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestion or idea to fulfil this curiosity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> function(result) {
>               alert('Done!');
>           },

The result (response) returned is not used and hence, you don't see the result. You can do something like this :

1. Add a tag with some id to your html
2. Put response from server in that tag.

E.g.

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Change javascript to

```
 function(result) {
     $("#result").html(result);
         },
```